# Syntax error : missing ';' before '^' in c++ managed

Tags: c++-cli

In `my_project.h` :

```
#pragma once

#include <vcclr.h>
#include "MyManagedClass.h"

namespace my_namespace 
{
   MyManagedClass^ DoSomething(const Foo* foo);
}
```

I have got next errors:

```
1) error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
2) error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
     Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Project has been created as `c++/cli`.

in `"MyManagedClass.h"` :

```
public ref class MyManagedClass
{
public:
System::UInt32 GetMember()
{
   return m_member;
}
private:
System::UInt32 m_member;
};
```

In other files everything works but here, what I did wrong ?

**ETA:**

I've modified the function like this:

```
namespace my_namespace 
{
   MyManagedClass^ DoSomething(const System::String^ str);
}
```

And it didn't solve the problem, but for some reason if I change return type to `void`, then everything works fine

Comment: where is the Foo definition? in vcclr.h?

Comment: @Carlos Quintanilla, in my case `Foo` is `char*`

Comment: are you sure the error says: missing ';' before '^' and not before '*'?

Comment: @Carlos Quintanilla, I'm sure

Comment: I'm asking because if the Foo type is not found then it says * and that's what I reproduced, so probably the program can't find MyManagedClass hence the ^ in the error message.

Comment: Can you have just a function like that outside of a class in CLI? Why not make it a static member function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created your issue, and got the same error. Removing the parameter `const Foo* foo` (making method DoSomething take no parameters) removed the error. I also tried adding `typedef char* Foo;`, and the error went away as well.

Check your definition of `Foo`, it looks like that's where the error is.

---

I copied & pasted your code into Visual Studio, there was no error on the `MyManagedClass` type. You'll need to show us more code if we're going to find the error.

Perhaps is `MyManagedClass` in a namespace that you forgot the `using namespace` directive for?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem in return type, if I make it void, the  error disappear

Comment: You'll need to show us more code to find the error. See edit.